# I have problems linking brew's vim version

Tags: vim, homebrew, macos-mojave

I'm trying to install vim with brew in Mac OS mojave, I can use it by introducing the entire direction in the terminal but when I type `vim` it uses the default one, and when I built it it showed this error:

```
==> Pouring vim-8.2.0750.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/man/de/man1/ex.1
/usr/local/share/man/de/man1 is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link vim
```

I tried linking it and it showed this error:

```
$ brew link vim
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.2.0750... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/de/man1/ex.1
/usr/local/share/man/de/man1 is not writable.
MacBook-Air-de-Carlos:~ julian$
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to set ownership on `/usr/local/share` with:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set ownership on `/usr/local/share/man` with:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share
```

`/usr/local/share/man` is sufficient.